How to write INT to terminal in Transaction Application Language
Today is my first day working with TAL (Transaction Application Language) on a Guardian operating system at my workplace, both new to me. I plan to start by writing some small programs.
I already know how to write "Hello, World" to the terminal:
?NOLIST,SOURCE $SYSTEM.SYSTEM.EXTDECS (CLOSE, INITIALIZER
  OPEN,WRITE,MYTERM)
?LIST

PROC myproc MAIN;
BEGIN
 INT termname[0:11];
 INT filename;
 STRING buffer [0:79]; 
 
 CALL INITIALIZER;
 CALL MYTERM (termname);
 CALL OPEN (termname, filename); 
 CALL WRITE(filename, "Hello World", 12);
 CALL CLOSE(out_file_number); 
END;

But I wish to write out an INT.
How can I do that?

Use NUMOUT. It is documented in the Guardian Procedure Calls Reference Manual IIRC.
